# Generation of XSD restrictions in a schema generated from Java JAXB annotated classes

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, moxy

MOXy [BeanValidation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/BVinJAXB/GettingStarted) gives me the ability to add validation to my JAXB classes.

Using MOXy's "Bean Validation Plugin" I can have Bean Validation in generated JAXB classes based on [restrictions/facets](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp) from a *prexisting* Schema.

However is there any way of *generating a schema* with [restrictions/facets](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp)based on  Bean Validation annotations *from a JAXB annotated java class*?

XJC has a handy plugin architecture when doing 'schema first' generating java, but is there any equivalent 'java first' way to enhance the generated XSD with additional restrictions, or even to add XML comments ? Either in MOXy or JAXB-RI?

MOXy is extremely flexible with meet in the middle mappings, can this be used during schema generation?

The [jaxb-facets project](https://github.com/whummer/jaxb-facets) seems to do what I want but the implementer had to fork an entire new JAXB-RI to get it in and it seems that it won't be adopted any time soon.([See this Java JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-917))

---

I tried the resolution specified by @m0mus but had to use the 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT versions from the sonatype repository. I still had a couple of problems;
1. I had to annotate the java fields with @XmlElement to get the facets to appear in the xsd. @XmlAttribute, @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) made no difference. @Pattern did not work; I had to work around with a single Pattern in Pattern.List;

```
@XmlElement
@Pattern.List(value = { @Pattern(regexp="[0-9]*") })
public String phoneNumber2;
```

For more info see the [EclipseLink Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1070043/)

Comment: Currently @XmlAttribute and @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) are not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is there. MOXy uses its own SchemaGen implementation for the process of generating XSD files from Java classes. SchemaGen was extended to automatically generate XSD Restrictions and Facets based on BV annotations found on Java classes. Since the schema generation process takes place upon creation of JAXBContext, the BV enhancement feature can be turned on/off by setting the following property (found in JAXBContextProperties) on JAXBContext:

```
/**
 * Property for disabling/enabling generation of XML Facets during schemagen.
 * The mapped value must be of type Boolean.
 * If it's true, then facets will be generated, based on the BV annotations.
 * If false, the BV annotations processing will be skipped during schemagen
 * and no facets will be generated.
 *
 * @since 2.6
 */
public static final String GENERATE_FACETS = "eclipselink.generate.facets";
```

SchemaGen recognizes annotations provided by the BV API, including @Pattern.List. If SchemaGen encounters a field annotated with both @NotNull and @XmlElement(nillable = true), it will raise the BeanValidationException.notNullAndNillable().

Sample:

```
Map props = new HashMap( );
props.put("eclipselink.beanvalidation.facets", true);
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, properties);
SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MSOR();
jc.generateSchema(sor);
```

Comment: see comments in question below the horiziontal rule;

Answer (score 3):

Filed a request for enhancement to process `@XMLAttribute` fields: [Bugs Page](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478616)

The reason you need to use v2.7 is that in some unusual call trees for schema generation, the enable facets property value is not propagated down the call tree. It was [fixed](http://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime.git/commit/?id=e93e87f33c51288b717029d3de88aa463da5f331) on May 5th. Asked for backport to EL v2.6 [now](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463173).

Answer (score -1):

You could also look to xjc plugin https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools

By documentation it support `XJsr303Annotations` and can generate:

- `@Valid` annotation for all complex types, can be further restricted to generate only for types from defined schema: `-XJsr303Annotations:targetNamespace=http://www.foo.com/bar`
- `@NotNull` annotation for objects that has a `MinOccur` value >= 1 or for attributes with required use
- `@Size` for lists that have `minOccurs > 1`
- `@Size` if there is a `maxLength` or `minLength` or length restriction
- `@DecimalMax` for `maxInclusive` restriction
- `@DecimalMin` for `minInclusive` restriction
- `@DecimalMax` for `maxExclusive` restriction, enable new parameter `(inclusive=false)` with: `-XJsr303Annotations:JSR_349=true`
- `@DecimalMin` for `minExclusive` restriction, enable new parameter `(inclusive=false)` with: `-XJsr303Annotations:JSR_349=true`
- `@Digits` if there is a `totalDigits` or `fractionDigits` restriction.
- `@Pattern` if there is a `Pattern` restriction

If you wonder how to use XJC plugins in your build environment (`ant`, `maven`, `gradle`) I may recomment look at examples of another plugin: [immutable-xjc](https://github.com/sabomichal/immutable-xjc)

So I hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I extend answer with hope it more representative to concrete problem of question.